# Screen resolution messed up on Ubuntu 14.10 with Nvidia 331 driver

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, 14.10

I am using the Nvidia 331.89 (nvidia-331) driver as recommended by Ubuntu 14.10. When I boot my machine using an external monitor and my laptop's screen on, the displays are mirrored by default with differing resolutions. When I adjust the display settings to the correct settings (e.g. not mirrored so I can use both displays) and apply them, the resolution is set incorrectly to a very low resolution on both monitors. No matter what configuration I use it comes out wrong. The login screen, strangely enough, works perfectly fine. Resolutions are fine and both screens work. I have tried switching drivers, but whenever I switch, it crashes and reverts to nvidia-331. Any ideas what I should try? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried either a later version or a previous version of the driver?

Comment: I have the exact same issue when I add to that mix a second monitor on the mini display port.